# Partition a table on non-primary key column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

When I am trying to create a table partition on non-primary key column it is getting an error:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PartitionFuncByCntry (int) AS RANGE RIGHT
FOR VALUES  ('10','11','12','15');

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PartitionSchemeByCntry AS PARTITION
PartitionFuncByCntry TO
([PRIMARY],[PRIMARY],[PRIMARY],[PRIMARY],[PRIMARY]);

CREATE TABLE tblPartitionByCntry( memberId int PRIMARY KEY
identity(1,1), cntryId int, txt1 varchar(100), txt2 varchar(100), txt3
varchar(100), txt4 varchar(100) ) ON PartitionSchemeByCntry(cntryId);
```

> Msg 1908, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 Column 'cntryId' is partitioning
>   column of the index 'PK__tblPartitionByCn__0880433F'. Partition
>   columns for a unique index must be a subset of the index key. Msg
>   1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 16 Could not create constraint. See
>   previous errors.

How to make partition on non primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_DateTime(datetime2)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES("values here");

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_DateTime
AS PARTITION PF_DateTime ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Example(
  ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY
    --non-partitioned PK
    CONSTRAINT PK_Example PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ID) ON [PRIMARY]
, DateTime datetime2
    --partitioned non-unique clustered index
    INDEX cdx CLUSTERED ON PS_DateTime(DateTime)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try creating to apply the Partition Scheme to the table after creating it with Primary Key, like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[RowTrip] 
(
  [id] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Season] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Distance] [decimal] not null
  CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_ROWTRIP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id ASC)
)
GO

CREATE INDEX [CI_ROWTRIP_BY_SEASON] ON [dbo].[RowerTrip]
(
    [Season]
) ON [PS_BY_SEASON]([Season])
```

PS_BY_SEASON is your: PartitionSchemeByCntry